# CSS- Centering child text wider than parent container

Tags: html, css

[Here's a JSfiddle of what I have so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/beartits/35waA/)

What I want to do is make it so that the text "Text With a Border" is centered inside of the parent div (I want to keep the double lined borders on either side of this text, so that the end result will be something like this: ==========Text With a Border==========. With the borders hanging off either side of the parent div.)

I would like to make it so that this solution works with containers of varying sizes with differing amounts of text.

I've found a few questions similar to this, about centering wide children inside of narrower parents, but for some reason I can't get them to work with this text.

CSS:

```
#container {
width:400px;
background:pink;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 10px 0;
}

.border {
display:block;
background:yellow;
}

.border span {
left:0;right:0;
white-space:nowrap;
margin: auto;
}

p.border span:after, p.border span:before {
content: " ";
display: inline-block;
width:100%;
height:5px;
border:solid gray;
border-width:1px 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<p class="border">
    <span>Text With a Border</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help,

Comment: are you looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/35waA/1/

Comment: Thank you, but not quite. I want to keep the borders and the text on one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use negative margin and overflow.

Negative margin to virtually reduce width, space needed by pseudo-elements down to zero,  :
http://jsfiddle.net/35waA/3/

```
#container {
    width:400px;
    background:pink;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.border {
    display:block;
    background:yellow;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.border span {
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
p.border span:after, p.border span:before {
    content:" ";
    display: inline-block;
    width:200%;
    height:5px;
    border:solid gray;
    border-width:1px 0;
}
p.border span:before {
    margin-left:-200%;
}
p.border span:after {
    margin-right:-200%;
}
```

Else , background-image /gradient will do too.

Comment: @KingKing indeed , because of white-space that keeps it on line :)

Comment: Thank you! This works really well, but if there's only a small amount of text between the borders (say one character) the borders won't be long enough to fill the rest of the remaining width. Any ideas?

Comment: give them at least half width of the parent (not in % cause it takes then width of span ). container is 400px, minimal would be : 200px with same value for negative margin.

Comment: Okay, so I updated the original fiddle in the op and for some reason it seems that setting them to 100% allows for fewer amounts of text. I really have no idea why any of this works or of what's happening.

Comment: @user2839712 just said :) , because if you use % to set width it takes the width of span as reference , longer is text, longer are pseudos, use static width instead and at least half of container 's width :)  http://jsfiddle.net/35waA/24/

Comment: Thank you, but I still feel like I'm having trouble getting it. It seems like the pseudos match the width of the span in some instances and not others. In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beartits/35waA/23/ the span is short but the pseudos are long. In this one the pseudos and the span are short http://jsfiddle.net/beartits/35waA/25/. Thanks for your help.

Comment: display:inline-block triggers layout to span, and then, becomes a reference usable for pseudo's width :)